# Why am I not able to update the Campaign Group total budget through the api?

Tags: linkedin-api

[image: Unable to update Campaign Group Budget]

Hi,
I'm trying to update the Total Budget of my campaign group(611595793) to $300 when there has been total spend of $166.78 on the campaign group.

The api call I'm using is: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2/611595793
with a request body of:

```
{
    "patch": {
        "$set": {
            "totalBudget": {
                "amount": "300.00",
                "currencyCode": "USD"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response I'm getting is:

> {"errorDetailType":"com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest","code":"FIELD_VALUE_TOO_LOW","message":"unspentTotalBudget value -142.07823692976003244 cannot be lower than 100.0000","errorDetails":{"inputErrors":[{"description":"unspentTotalBudget value -142.07823692976003244 cannot be lower than 100.0000","input":{"value":{"decimalValue":"300.00"},"inputPath":{"fieldPath":"/CampaignGroup/totalBudget/amount"}},"minValue":"100.0000","code":"FIELD_VALUE_TOO_LOW"}]},"status":400}

In the screenshot, you can see the api call with the new campaign group total budget, the api response, and the total spend on the campaign group.

Why is the unspentTotalBudget in the api response calculated to be -142.07823692976003244? If I am increasing the total budget to $300, shouldn't the unspentTotalBudget be $133.22? $133.22 should allow me to update the total budget since it is above the minValue of $100. Yet I'm not able to update the total budget and am getting this error message.
What is causing this rejection from the LinkedIn api?